# How do I get help with an issue involving an image which is meant to be confidential?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, legal

I was going to ask a question on a Stack Exchange website about why my website's [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) logo was appearing pixelated on my [HiDPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Named_pixel_densities) screen in the Safari browser.

The logo in question is an original graphic I designed for my company, but neither the design nor the wordmark/brand name are properly trademark protected at this point in time. Because of that, my logo design and brand names are confidential at the moment, so I worry that if I post my logo on the Internet, someone will find it and do something bad with it, which I of course don't have any control over without the proper trademark information.

How can I ask a question about, say, a vector graphic from my website appearing blurry on my HiDPI monitor, without actually revealing the graphic itself?

Comment: Would it be possible to create or find something else that reproduces the same issue, such as an SVG of a generic square? That potentially could work

Comment: Do none of the [existing questions help](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsvg%5D%5Bsafari%5Dblurry)? If you look through them perhaps you won't need to ask a question at all.

Comment: You should ask this question on a per-site meta corresponding to where the question might on-topic. The advice given in previous comments sounds appropriate but there it might be possible that you might need guidance to reproduce the problem. On some sites, troubleshooting-like questions aren't allowed but on others, they might be. Some sites have chatrooms that are focused on certain tags / problems. If you are part of the process to create the image, I think that you should make this a [tag:site-recommendation], but you should [edit] it accordingly.

Comment: @cocomac I did make a generic logo, but the problem is that it doesn't reproduce my issue like the actual logo does.

Answer (score 10):

This is asking the wrong Meta question. You **should be able to** demonstrate the problem using a non-confidential image, or else you **do not have a suitable question yet**.

> I did make a generic logo, but the problem is that it doesn't reproduce my issue like the actual logo does.

When trying to figure out a problem (do "debugging", roughly and broadly speaking) in a question for a computer-oriented Stack Exchange site, it's crucial to have a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE). (Similar reasoning applies for other technical sites: e.g. a question on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) about why a circuit didn't work, should show a circuit that reliably doesn't work in the specific way described, and is not more complex than necessary. To the extent that it's *physically safe* to figure this out, of course.)

If there is one specific SVG that causes the problem, that is just not going to be enough information to go on. Questions, and their examples, need to be self-contained; generally people are not going to download and inspect a file attachment to look for a specific problem with it. It's also important to develop basic [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) skills, and [apply them before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

I'm not an expert in web stuff, but I do know some basics about SVG and would generally consider myself an expert programmer. With that in mind, here are some things off the top of my head that I'd want to look into first if I were in your position:

- What happens if you try re-creating the actual logo from scratch? (You say the original is your own work, so I assume it shouldn't be *too* difficult to get a reasonable facsimile.)
- Do you have any kind of revision history for edits to the logo file? If so, did previous versions exhibit the same issue?
- What happens if you try opening the logo file in an appropriate editor and then re-saving it?

  - What if you make a trivial change before saving?
  - What if you try removing various graphical elements? Can you isolate a specific aspect of the logo that causes a problem? If you can, what if you *alter* that part slightly?
- What if you try other browsers, or other screens?
- What if you try changing the HTML to change the display width/height of the image?
- I assume you know (because you linked the Wikipedia article, which explains this) that SVG files are fundamentally just text files that contain XML. Did you try validating the file that you have? Maybe it got subtly corrupted somehow. How about if you make the sorts of edits described above at the XML level, by editing the XML in a text editor?

And then - rather than simply answering those questions preemptively in a Stack Exchange question, *use that discovery process* to try to create a MRE.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the place to ask for guidance might be on per-site Meta of [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

I'm unfamiliar with this site, but it looks like the problem you are facing should be something that the regulars from that site should be familiar with.

From Graphic Design Meta

- [Is it possible to delete images from SO server once they've been added to an answer?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/482/101026)
- [Post your Work In Progress (FKA: The Looking Glass)](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3649/101026)